# Visual Studio Docker Tools - where do the images go and where do the containers run

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-for-windows

In Docker for Desktop, I have the docker-for-desktop cluster selected (it's running on MobyLinuxVM on HyperV).

However, when I go to Visual Studio and build / debug a project that has Docker support, then run "docker ps -a" from a command line, I do not see another container created.  Does Visual Studio deploy a container by default to a separate cluster somehow?

Comment: Let's see, with the other services, I built them from the command line with "docker build" and ran with "docker run".  In Visual Studio, I guess it's using "docker compose".  I'll have to explore the differences.

Comment: OK - it wasn't creating images or containers because docker-compose wasn't selected as the startup project.  Also, I see that docker automatically creates a bridge network that all services listed in docker-compose.yml share.  So if you want to access a database running on the host, do a "docker network ls" and "docker network inspect <network name starting with dockercompose>" to find the gateway IP - that will be the host's "localhost"/127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

I set the docker-compose project as the startup project (not sure why it wasn't already).  Also, there were problems with the docker-compose.yml formatting I had caused while struggling to understand why it wasn't running.

Note that if you don't specify a network, docker-compose will automatically create a bridge network that all the services in docker-compose will share (they have to use this network's gateway to see services on the other containers).  Across builds, it often will increment the bridge network gateway IP's second octet.  My workaround to having to change the gateway IP constantly was making a user defined bridge network and adding the following to the bottom of docker-compose.yml (it gets used by all the services in the file):

```
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: mybridgenetwork
```

Another helpful thing is that I was able to pass in multiple environment variables to a single service in docker-compose.yml like this:

```
services:
   myservice1:
      "envVariable1" : "somevalue"
      "envVariable2" : "somevalue"
```

Also, I was able to make it pull from the local docker registry (if Kubernetes is enabled on Docker Desktop, then you can set the context that docker-compose will run against by right clicking the Docker icon, going to the kubernetes submenu, then selecting the context.  If you do not see a docker-desktop context there, issue a "docker swarm init" command from powershell or command (run as administrator).
Then, add the following to docker-compose.yml's image lines in order to get docker compose to detect the built images in the local Docker for Windows registry:

```
image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}TheImageNameYouWant
```

Note that the container names will be called dockercompose[some random string]_[the image name above].  You can see these running containers in powershell (as admin) by doing "docker ps -a".

One last thing - make sure that Visual Studio / Tools / Options / Container Tools has "Automatically kill containers on solution close" checked.  If you think you might want to change docker-compose.yml before it runs the first time on startup, uncheck the first two checkboxes.